# Aggregate a DataFrame column by counting special elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `b` in the following format:

```
   chip sampleid  WL     ok
0     1     test   4   True
1     2     test   4  False
```

If I want to count number of True elements in `b['ok']`, I can run this:

```
In [125]: sum(b['ok'])
Out[125]: 1
```

I now want to group this DataFrame by `sampleid` and count the chips as well as the number of True elements in the ok column.

```
In [121]: c = b.groupby('sampleid', as_index=False).aggregate({'chip': lambda x: len(x.unique()), 'ok': sum})

In [122]: c
Out[122]:
  sampleid  chip    ok
0     test     2  True
```

Why is this behaviour different than from above? How can I count the elements in the column? The expected output is:

```
  sampleid  chip    ok
0     test     2     1
```

Comment: Could be a bug, this happens on my pandas `0.14.0` version

Comment: Any obvious workaround?

Comment: You'd have to convert the boolean values to int `1` and `0` in order for this to work as it stands and then convert back to boolean values, not ideal though

Answer (score 0):

This clearly is a bug, `aggregate` will try to convert the result to the same `dtype` the original `DataFrame` has. Here the `sum` will return `1` and `bool(1)` is `True`. If both of the values in `ok` are `False`s, the result will be `False` (`bool(0)`). Further examples:

```
In [85]:

print df.groupby('sampleid', as_index=False).aggregate({'chip': lambda x: len(x.unique()), 
                                                        'ok': lambda x: np.mean(x)})
  sampleid  chip   ok
0     test     2  0.5 #somehow if a float(?) is returned, converting doesn't happen , despite of bool(0.5)==True 
In [87]:

print df.groupby('sampleid', as_index=False).aggregate({'chip': lambda x: len(x.unique()), 
                                                        'ok': lambda x: np.ptp(x)})
  sampleid  chip    ok
0     test     2  True #np.ptp() will return 1 and bool(1)==True
```